# Only display blog posts with description on website

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm pulling the 3 latest blog posts on the homepage of a website through the rss feed.
This is the code:

```
<div class="wpTest"> 
 <div class="wpContent_wrapper">
   <ul class="wpContent_slider">
    <?php $channel = new Zend_Feed_Rss('https://www.test.co.uk/blog/feed/'); ?>
     <?php $i = 0; ?>
      <?php foreach ($channel as $item): ?>
       <li class="wpContent">
<?php if ($i < 3) : // number of articles ?>
    <a title="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"></a>
    <p><div class="wp_content_main" id="test1"><a title="<?php echo $item->title;?>" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo limitWords($item->description()); ?> <?php echo '....' ?></a></div></p>
    <div class="wp_content_button"><a title="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" class="wp_more">Read More</a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
</li>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
</div> 
</div>
```

Now my issue is that the way some of the blog posts are set up they don't have a description in the rss feed. So if that is the case I don't want to display them.
I've tried doing a if statement for this but it didn't work.

```
   <?php if ($item->description() !== '' && $item->description()  !== NULL): ?>
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: `if(!$item->description()) ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `empty` function of PHP to check if the description exists.

Also, put the `<li>` tag and the incrementation of the `$i` inside the `if` condition.

i.e. :

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($channel as $item): ?>
    <?php if ($i < 3 && !empty($item->description())) : // number of articles ?>
        <li class="wpContent">
            <a title="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"></a>
            <p><div class="wp_content_main" id="test1"><a title="<?php echo $item->title;?>" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>"><?php echo limitWords($item->description()); ?> <?php echo '....' ?></a></div></p>
            <div class="wp_content_button"><a title="<?php echo $item->title; ?>" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" class="wp_more">Read More</a></div>
        </li>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `->description()` is a method not a class member - if you try to use `isset()` you'll just get : **Fatal error:** Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call...

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)  function.

```
<?php if (!empty($item->description()) ) {
```

You could also just use the `$item->description()` without the empty function, using PHP's type juggling but this can be unreliable.

Comment: In this instance `$item->description()` is no less reliable than `!empty($item->description())` ... we **know** the `description()` method exists so either way we're just checking for *truthiness* ...